# Android camera2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (1) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more

Tags: android, image, reader, camera2

Hello having trouble to fix this issue.

I already have a imageReader.close called inside the ImageAvailable callback but still having the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (1) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.

Code I have is here:

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image img = mReader.acquireLatestImage();

        mReader.close();
    }

};
```

ps. I also use the argument reader as well but not seem to solve the problem

Comment: I think I solved. The img have to be closed not the ImageReader.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok I have solved my problem. I need to close the img object not the ImageReader.

Comment: Accept your own answer please

Comment: Can you show where you access the image I only have a reader and a file no image

Comment: where did you close the `img` object. answer is not clear

Comment: this is not helpful without more details

Comment: where did you close the img object

Answer (score 3):

```
    private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your SD card is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(data);
        image.close();//after you use the image's content ,you can close it
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
        String picturePath = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        imgFile = new File(filePath, picturePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
        try {//Store to folder
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(data);
            fileOutputStream.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startEditPictureActivity(uri, imgFile);


    }
};
```

Comment: Please add explanation along with answer.

Answer (score 1):

`close()` needs to be called on the `Image` object that `acquireLatestImage()` returns.

So, going from the OP's implementation of `onImageAvailable()` in his sample, **just adding `.close()` after the `acquireLatestImage()` should do the trick.**
Like so:

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage().close(); // Note the added `close()` call.
}
```

I should also add that **the `image` will no longer be usable after you call `close()` on it** (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#close())).
So the solution I've mentioned above will get you rid off the exception OP mentioned, but you also won't be able to do anything with the `image`. This is obviously easy to fix by first doing whatever you want with the `image` and only then calling `close()` on it.